# Compare two files using the first word and returning the second

Tags: shell, unix

I'm writing a korn shell script to try and compare one file that contains usernames, to another file that has usernames with emails.  Examples are below:

file1:

```
user1
user2
user5
```

file2:

```
user1|email1
user2|email2
user3|email3
user4|email4
user5|email5
```

Is there anyway I can return only the emails for the matching usernames to file3 like this?  I think I have to use the comm command but I'm not sure how to exactly go about it.

file3:

```
email1
email2
email5
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another solution :

```
grep -f file_1 file_2 | cut -d '|' -f2
```

But grep is not so robust, it can find false positives. If you want it to be robust, adapt file 1 like this :

```
\buser1@
\buser2@
\buser5@
```

You should threat files lines by lines programmatically instead.

Comment: One another way to more secure is set field separator to "|" and add -w(exact word match) to grep

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However when I try to run grep with -f I get it as an illegal option.  When I use -w it runs through both the files and says grep can't open each of the lines.

Comment: Do man grep and see if your version of grep allows for -f option .
Mine grep allows 

     grep -wf file_1 file_2 | cut -d '|' -f2

Comment: Doing man grep shows that -f can be used when it has pattern file after, like -f pattern file

Comment: @VarmintCong Then you should be able to use 
      
      `grep-wf file_1 file_2 | cut -d"|" -f2`

here file_1 will be pattern file -w has been used to signify exact word match

Comment: @ajay Still can't get it.  I have tried -wf and -f still getting `grep illegal option -- f`.  Under that it has `Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file...`.  When I do man grep though it still mentions -f pattern file.  It mentions this in the same section that -E is in

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution seems with `join` :

```
join -t '|' file_1 file_2 | cut -d '|' -f2
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I would be joining here.  If I'm trying to compare  a string in file1 to a string in file2 I think I would need to be using comm or grep